# Css flex with equal

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want a `flex` parent with equal width items plus margin, I used `flex: 1 0 15%` but the problem is I don't want two last items get full width of row. First row has six items, right? second row has two row (7 & 8) width full width, see snippet below:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  flex: 1 0 15%;
  background: darkseagreen;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

My goal is to get this result but with equal width, prefer `flex`:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  background: darkseagreen;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 15%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you already got your result, so what is the issue?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Checkout the answer below to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `flex: 1 0 15%;` here is the shorthand of `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`.

If you want the last two item not being grow. Set `flex-grow` to 0. Or you can do this:

```
ul li {
  flex: 0 0 15%;
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to use up the whole container width, here is a suggestion.

```
ul li {
  flex: 0 0 calc((100% - 12 * 5px) / 6);
}
```

Comment: But in this solution items has not equal width to parent (container)

Comment: It is because 100% divided by 6 is 16.66% to be exact.